# Use groovy plugin and jboss tool simultaneously in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I have a project that uses groovy and java code. The project is deployed as a war file in jboss and it works fine (at least it deploys and I get some output through my browser). I now want to debug the code and I thought eclipse should do the trick. However it seems like I cannot use both groovy plugin and jboss plugin simultaneously in eclipse. Is this the case? Is there a workaround?

System:

- Ubuntu Precise Pangolin
- Eclipse Juno
- Jboss tools for Indigo (Juno is unstable)
- Groovy-eclipse for juno

I have groovy-eclipse installed and when I try to install Jboss tools (from marked place) I get:

> Software being installed: JBoss Central Community 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final (org.jboss.tools.community.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final)
>     Software currently installed: VMware vFabric tc Server Integration for Eclipse 3.1.0.201210040536-RELEASE (com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040536-RELEASE)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       Mylyn Commons UI 3.6.1.v20110720-0100 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.6.1.v20110720-0100)
>       Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.2.v20120916-1200 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.2.v20120916-1200)
>       Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.0.v20120612-0600 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.0.v20120612-0600)
>       Mylyn Commons UI 3.4.0.v20100608-0100-e3x (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.4.0.v20100608-0100-e3x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution my self. I was installing a package consisting of groovy and grails tools and

- Grails IDE
- SpringSource
- VMware vFabric

caused the conflicts with jboss tools. Since I only needed the groovy compiler I could untick those. I guess I could also have chosen a different package.